# Winter Bash 2014!

Tags: discussion, event, winterbash

Technically not really a valid question but ..

Winter Bash 2014 is near. The question is if we are opting in?

Please post your answers below. I personally say "Aye!".

Comment: First I've heard about it (but I wasn't active on SE this time last year). What is it exactly, something about hats from the little I can find out?!?

Comment: Here it the one from the last year - http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/12/winter-bash-2013-is-here/

Comment: Ah right thanks, seeing as my avatar doesn't show a face not much use for me. Don't mind a bit of harmless fun over the Christmas period though!

Answer (score 9):

/me says Aye!
/me needs more then 30 characters for an answer
/me steals all your upvotes, because its easier to upvote me then to write an own answer or comment

Comment: Yarr! (+10 more characters)

Answer (score 3):

Sure...more useless free incentives.

<sub>I voted for Flyingmana's answer and written my own, just to show I'm not lazy.</sub>

Comment: Can't work out if this is a yes or no  ;)

Comment: @JonathanHussey. Great. I was aiming for that.

Comment: Come on, your opinion is the most important as you will have most of the hats in your arsenal.

Comment: @TimBezhashvyly. There is no such thing as "the most important opinion". All of the opinions are equally (in)valid. Should we start a betting session on who gets the most hats? And just to clear it...I'm all for the hat stuff.